# How to place top menu to left side bar in magento 2?

Tags: magento2, layout, frontend, menu, topmenu

I have magento 2 installed & working fine. I have a file in `app/design/frontend/vendor/theme/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml`

In that from top reference `<referenceContainer name="page.top">` I copied this block:

```
<block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="store.menu" group="navigation-sections" template="Magento_Theme::html/container.phtml">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="title" translate="true" xsi:type="string">Menu</argument>
    </arguments>
</block>
```

which is used to show top menu & pasted that in new reference (created a new reference):

```
<referenceContainer name="sidebar.main">
    <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="store.menu" group="navigation-sections" template="Magento_Theme::html/container.phtml">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="title" translate="true" xsi:type="string">Menu</argument>
        </arguments>
    </block>
</referenceContainer>
```

so the whole file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
* Copyright © 2015 Magento. All rights reserved.
* See COPYING.txt for license details.
*/
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="header.container">
            <container name="header.panel.wrapper" htmlClass="panel wrapper" htmlTag="div" before="-"/>
        </referenceContainer>

        <move element="header.panel" destination="header.panel.wrapper"/>
        <move element="top.links" destination="header.panel" after="-"/>
        <move element="catalog.topnav" destination="store.menu" before="-"/>

        <referenceContainer name="page.top">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="navigation.sections" before="-" template="Magento_Theme::html/sections.phtml">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="group_name" xsi:type="string">navigation-sections</argument>
                    <argument name="group_css" xsi:type="string">nav-sections</argument>
                </arguments>
                <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="store.menu" group="navigation-sections" template="Magento_Theme::html/container.phtml">
                    <arguments>
                        <argument name="title" translate="true" xsi:type="string">Menu</argument>
                    </arguments>
                </block>
                <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Text" name="store.links" group="navigation-sections">
                    <arguments>
                        <argument name="title" translate="true" xsi:type="string">Account</argument>
                        <argument name="use_force" xsi:type="boolean">true</argument>
                        <argument name="text" xsi:type="string"><![CDATA[<!-- Account links -->]]></argument>
                    </arguments>
                </block>
                <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="store.settings" group="navigation-sections" template="Magento_Theme::html/container.phtml">
                    <arguments>
                        <argument name="title" translate="true" xsi:type="string">Settings</argument>
                    </arguments>
                    <block class="Magento\Store\Block\Switcher" name="store.settings.language" template="switch/languages.phtml">
                        <arguments>
                            <argument name="id_modifier" xsi:type="string">nav</argument>
                        </arguments>
                    </block>
                    <block class="Magento\Directory\Block\Currency" name="store.settings.currency" before="store_language" template="currency.phtml">
                        <arguments>
                            <argument name="id_modifier" xsi:type="string">nav</argument>
                        </arguments>
                    </block>
                </block>
            </block>
        </referenceContainer>

        <referenceContainer name="sidebar.main">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="store.menu" group="navigation-sections" template="Magento_Theme::html/container.phtml">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="title" translate="true" xsi:type="string">Menu</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
        </referenceContainer>

    </body>
</page>
```

Now the problem is when I do the above change then top menu appears in left side bar but from top menu, it becomes disappeared. I don't know how to solve it. If I change the name of that then it is not coming so name must be same i.e. `store.menu`.

Anyone can please explain how to solve this?

Thank You.

Comment: Any suggestion please?

Comment: Any Suggestion please?

Answer (score 3):

When you first install Magento 2 the home page is displayed using the 1 column layout. you should make a custom layout or modify the 2 Column layout to move the catalog.topnav element to the sidebar.

Comment: how that can be achieved? please share the code to change